# # syntax in C (conversion?)

Tags: c

I have the following statement in a piece of code:

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
```

What does this do to s, if s is an integer such as 96? Is this a conversion to a string literal, such as "96"?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, and you can easily test it out: https://godbolt.org/z/r6d4bGf81